# EOFexception in Java when reading objectinputstream

Tags: java, objectoutputstream, eofexception

I want to read multiple objects (my own class Term) that I have output to a .dat file, but I always get a nullPointException or EOFException.

```
ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(masterFile));
        Object o = null;
        while(( o = inputStream.readObject()) != null){
            Term t = (Term)o;
            System.out.println("I found a term");
        }
```

Comment: If you get an EOFException, it's probably because you've reached the end of the file.

Comment: yes, i assume it's reaching the end of the file.

Comment: I've tried this and I only ever get EOFException. Under what circumstances do you get NullPointerException?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451232/eofexception-how-to-handle?s=0|5.4926

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the Javadoc. `readObject()` doesn't return null at EOF. It throws `EOFException.` The only way it can return a null is if you wrote a null at the other end, and that's not necessarily a good reason for terminating the read loop.

In short your code is wrong.

NB the initialization of 'o' is redundant.

NB (2) The code you posted cannot throw `NullPointerException,` unless `masterFile` is null. Is that a serious report or just a guess?

Comment: How do you solve the `EOFException` problem? Should I wrap the code in a `try/catch` block and wait for the exception to arise>

Comment: It's not a 'problem', it's an exception. Catch it.